# TWIG: Loop through attributes/getters in entity

Tags: symfony, twig

I have an Entity `MyLists` which has an attribute `lists` which is an array collection. This array Collection has `list`-entities:

```
class List 
{
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $date;

    public function setName($name) {
        ...
    }

    public function getName() {
       return $this->name;
    }
        ...
}
```

Ist it possible to loop through all these getters in TWIG? For example:

```
{% for list in myList.lists %}
   {% for getter in list %}
       {{ list.getter }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Twig is not able to loop over object properties. You could transform your object to an array, then you can do `{% for key, value in my_object_as_array %}...{% endfor %}`

Comment: You could have your List class implement the php iterator interface http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php.

Answer (score -2):

If `myList` is an array containing object :

```
{% for list in myList.lists %}
  {{ list.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Or :

```
{% for list in myList %}
  {{ list.lists.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Not one of the down voters but read the question carefully.  Your answer does not address the question.